# Using Google Apps Sync with Outlook 2007/2010 and iPads/iPhones

Tags: google-apps

**A little background: We use Google Apps for business and are having issues with some users inadvertently becoming meeting owners or moving meeting locations or times on accident.**
Every user in my company is an admin on their own machine. Users are encouraged to bring their own devices but there's no guarantee that they will be properly set up unless they ask the help desk for help.

My supervisor is asking me to post and as you guys: is there any other testing that I should be doing? Any other ideas? *Has anyone else using Google Calendars had attendees inadvertently move meeting times or locations when they are not the meeting owner?*

**Test Setup:**
Types of Setup for PCs or iPads: Outlook 2007 with Google Apps Sync on PC, Outlook 2010 with Google Apps Sync on PC, Google Calendar in Browser on PC, Google Calendar in iPad set up as Google (this is the setup recommended and supported by Google), Google Calendar in iPad set up as Exchange (this set up is neither recommended nor supported by Google)
**Test Cases:**
From Machine A to B Accept
From Machine A to B Decline
From Machine A to B, A Change meeting time, Accept
From Machine A to B, B Change meeting time, Accept
From Machine A to B, A Change meeting time, Decline
From Machine A to B, B Change meeting time, Decline
From Machine A to B, A Move meeting location, Accept
From Machine A to B, B Move meeting location, Accept
From Machine A to B, A Move meeting location, Decline
From Machine A to B, B Move meeting location, Decline

**Results:**

- Outlook 2010:

No issues found. The meeting owner could move the location or time of the meeting but the meeting (attendee sent notification automatically) attendee could only suggest other times and could not move the meeting to another location.

- Outlook 2007:

  Issue found. The meeting owner could move the time and location of the meeting (attendee sent notification automatically) but the meeting attendee could move the time of the meeting but not the location.
- Google Calendar in Browser:

No issues found. The meeting owner could move the location or time of the meeting but the meeting (attendee sent notification automatically) attendee was notified to contact the meeting owner and could not move the meeting time or location.

- iPad as Google:

No issues found. The meeting owner could move the location or time of the meeting but the meeting (attendee sent notification automatically) attendee was notified to contact the meeting owner and could not move the meeting time or location. The attendee could move the meeting on their own calendar but it was not reflected in the actual event.

- iPad as Exchange:

Issues found.  The attendee could move both the time and location of the meeting and these changes do not notify the meeting owner.

**Recommendations:** All PCs should be set up as Outlook 2010 using Google Apps Sync and all iPads and iPhones should be set up as Google. For any future calendar issues that occur the Help Desk must be notified and forwarded the original invitation (including .ics attachment) immediately upon discovering the issue so that we can notify Google Technical Support.